# How can I create a bookmarklet to manipulate this URL?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I'm trying to create a bookmarklet which will change the URL of the current page as follows:

Orginal URL:

```
http://website.com/games/game-title/lobby/lobbyID/
```

Edited URL:

```
http://website.com/external/game-chooser/lobbyID/
```

In the original URL, "games" and "lobby" will always be exactly "games" and "lobby" but "game-title" and "lobbyID" will vary.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
javascript:location.href='http://website.com/external/game-chooser/'+location.href.split('lobby/')[1]
```